# Finding datetime difference between lists in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, datetime

I'm new to python. I've looked at previous threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878175/create-a-list-of-datetime-objects-using-datetime-strptime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428678/convert-list-to-datetime-in-pandas). I have a Series of dates and times that created this way:

```
tp1=[]
for f in files: ### files is the variable that has all the files I need to read in this loop
 t=f[-19:-5] ### these characters in the filename correspond to the date and time
 tp1.append(datetime.strptime(t,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
time_p1_cr=pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(tp1), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

tp1 looks like:

```
[datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 16, 6, 39),

datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 2, 17, 16, 37),

datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 3, 10, 53, 46),

datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 3, 17, 14, 39),

datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 4, 11, 21, 36),

datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 4, 17, 27, 54),
```

and so on.
time_p1_cr looks like :

```
0    2018-08-01 16:06:39

1    2018-08-02 17:16:37

2    2018-08-03 10:53:46

3    2018-08-03 17:14:39
```

and so on. I need to find the successive differences between the elements of the list.  I basically need the time difference. I can't do

```
t2=tp1[1:]
t3=tp1[:-1]
t4=t3-t2
```

because t2, and t3 are lists and I can't subtract lists.

So, I tried

```
test1=time_p1_cr[1:]
test2=time_p1_cr[:-1]
test3=test1.subtract(test2)
```

according to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.subtract.html).
But test3 turns out to be

test3

```
0       NaT

1    0 days

2    0 days

3    0 days

4    0 days

5    0 days

6    0 days

7    0 days
```

and so on. How can I get the time difference between the successive elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do this. For example:

```
differences = [t2 - t1 for t1,t2 in zip(time_p1_cr[:-1], time_p1_cr[1:])]
```

This will give you a list of `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you. :-)